# Why can issue this error in the log?

Tags: error, log

Why can issue this error in the log?

2014-10-16T09:48:55+00:00 ERR (3): User Notice: 'hashed_directory_umask' is deprecated -> please use 'hashed_directory_perm' instead  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php on line 144

Comment: Whats the full call stack?

Comment: Are you using Lesti FPC? This might be related: https://github.com/GordonLesti/Lesti_Fpc/pull/51

Answer (score 1):

The error says, your PHP version is too new, please use the new PHP function `hashed_directory_perm` instead of the old one `hashed_directory_umask`.

I'm sure this is fixed in later Zend versions, so update magento or Zend and this problem is fixed.

Comment: I would like to comment that this is an issue with up to Magento 1.9.2.3 under PHP 5.6. The logs can be annoying. But running Magento in developer mode will bring this up as a blocking error. It can be fixed by editing the mentioned file `lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php` and then commenting out all the lines starting with `trigger_error(` and mentioning that a certain function is deprecated. All the warnings on core hacks apply here!